# How to return matching column value where only all subqueries are true

Tags: sql

I'd like to adjust the below SQL statement so that it only returns the `PART_ID` where all `SELECT PART_ID FROM FABRICATION...` conditions are met.

Currently the below statement would return part_id's 1 & 2, when the intent is to only return 1.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Part 
WHERE Section = 'C6x1_5/8x1/4' 
  AND Length BETWEEN 41.99 AND 42.01 
  AND Part.Part_ID IN (SELECT Part_ID FROM Fabrication 
                       WHERE Type LIKE 'HOLE' 
                         AND Face = 1 
                         AND Side = 3 
                         AND Location BETWEEN 2.99 AND 3.01 
                         AND Offset = 2 
                         AND Parameter_1 = 0.5625)
  AND Part.Part_ID IN (SELECT Part_ID FROM Fabrication 
                       WHERE Type LIKE 'HOLE' 
                         AND Face = 1 
                         AND Side = 3 
                         AND Location BETWEEN 5.99 AND 6.01 
                         AND Offset = 2 
                         AND Parameter_1 = 0.5625)
```

Fabrication Table:

| PART_ID | TYPE | FACE | SIDE | LOCATION | OFFSET | PARAMETER_1 | PARAMETER_2 | PARAMETER_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | HOLE | 1 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 0.5625 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | HOLE | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0.5625 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | HOLE | 1 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 0.5625 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | HOLE | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0.5625 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | HOLE | 1 | 3 | 9 | 2 | 0.5625 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | HOLE | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 0.5625 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: in the 2  subquery where conditions, I see "location" is the only different range. In your dataset, the part_id 1 & 2 has location values as 3 & 6 which are in range of 2.99-3.01 & 5.99-6.01. so the result set returning of 1 & 2 is correct!!- I tried something in here- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8bfa4/3

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `HAVING` to validate that there there is exactly one match for each condition and no others:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Part 
WHERE Section = 'C6x1_5/8x1/4' AND
      Length BETWEEN 41.99 AND 42.01 
      Part.Part_ID IN (SELECT f.Part_ID
                       FROM Fabrication f
                       GROUP BY f.Part_ID
                       HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN f.Type = 'HOLE' AND f.Face = 1 AND f.Side = 3 AND f.Offset = 2 AND f.Parameter_1 = 0.5625 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) AND
                              SUM(CASE WHEN Location BETWEEN 2.99 AND 3.01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND
                              SUM(CASE WHEN Location BETWEEN 5.99 AND 6.01 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only variance in your two queries is `Location`, for which you want to ensure the number of Fabrication rows meet your criteria and do not have any additional rows outside of your criteria.

One option you can try uses conditional aggregation:

```
select * 
from Part 
where Section = 'C6x1_5/8x1/4' 
    and Length between 41.99 and 42.01 
    and Part.Part_ID in (
        select PART_ID
        from Fabrication
        where 
        TYPE = 'HOLE' 
        and FACE = 1 
        and SIDE = 3 
        and offset = 2 
        and PARAMETER_1 = 0.5625
        group by PART_ID
        having Count(*)=Sum(case when LOCATION between 2.99 and 3.01 then 1 end) + Sum(case when LOCATION between 5.99 and 6.01 then 1 end) 
)
```